# owslib WebFeatureService (wfs) authentication

Tags: python, django, gis, geo, ogc

I am working since recently with the owsLib (see http://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/ )

I am trying to connect to a WFS but need to authenticate.

I saw you can give a username and password to the wms but not to the wfs.

Anybody any clue how to get this done?

Or should I clone the source and adjust it? (see https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib)
This should not be too difficult, because I could follow the example of the wms ...
But I cannot imagine I am the first one trying to logon to a wfs....

All examples and tutroials and docs I have found use open WFS (so no logong needed)

**Edit 5-3-2014**

I found 2 issues in the github, related to this problem:

First the missing docs is not very helpfull:
https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib/issues/70

Second, this probably will solve my issue, but is probably lon term:
https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib/issues/111

and I signed in to the owslib user community, so I could email my issue to this group.. (http://lists.osgeo.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/owslib-users)

**Edit 2014 march 06**

The response from the user group is, to wait for ticket 111 to be resolved...

Another option is just using the regular python connections myselve... the things I want to ask is not that complex...

Answer (score 0):

use HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm() to create a password manager. Then, use this to add a username password to the manager. Next, create an authorization manager by 
assing the password manager to HTTPBasicAuthHandler. Then, build an opener and install the opener into urllib2.

Do this before calling the owslib routines (for a wfs reader, for example.) It works just fine.

I would include the code but am away from it right now. In the meantime, i'll include a link to an example (bad form, i know) provided by the author of python Requests.
https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/973705

Comment: Hi. Was this usable?